Why do $E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_n)|X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1},x) = E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1}, x, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)|X_{k+1},\ldots, X_{n})$
The context for the question is from here: 
Let $X=(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ be a random vector with independent coordinates and let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.
To summarize the relevant part, the author says that $\tag A E(f(X)|x_1,\ldots,x_k) = E_{k+1}(f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, X_{k+1},\ldots, X_n))$ where $E_{k+1}$ denotes the expectation over $(X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)$. From this, the author says it follows that $\tag B E(f(X)|X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1}, x) = E_{k+1}(f(X_1,\ldots, X_{k-1}, x, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n))$.
I do not understand why either $A$ or $B$ holds. And I do not understand why $A$ would imply $B$.
For example, why is it the case that
$$ \tag 1 E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_n)|X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1},x) = E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1}, x, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)|X_{k+1},\ldots, X_{n})$$ holds?
In equation 1, I interpret the LHS $E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_n)|X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1},x)$ as $E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1}, x, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)|X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1})$.
I can use that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $E(\phi(X,Y)|X) = g(X)$, where $g(x) = E(\phi(x,Y))$.
Hence, $\tag 2 E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1}, x, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)|X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1}) = g_1(X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1})$, where $\tag 3 g_1(x_1, \ldots, x_{k-1}) = E(f(x_1, \ldots, x_{k-1}, x, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n))$.
Likewise,
$\tag 4 E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1}, x, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)|X_{k+1},\ldots, X_{n}) = g_2(X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_{n})$, where $\tag 5 g_2(x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_n) = E(f(X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1}, x, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_n))$
I can't see why $g_1(X_1, \ldots, X_{k-1})$ and $g_2(X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)$ should be equal.
It apparently follows because of the fact that
$$\tag 6 E(f(X)|x_1, \ldots, x_k) = E(f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)|X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)$$, but again I find that $\tag 7 E(f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)|X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n) = g_3(X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)$ with $\tag 8 g_3(x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_n) = E f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, x_{k+1}, \ldots, x_n)$, so $\tag 9 E(f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)|X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)$, while $\tag {10} E(f(X)|x_1, \ldots, x_k) = E(f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n))$, which do not seem equal.
Thank you.

It looks like the author uses this property with some idiosyncratic notation.

@KurtG. That's the property I'm using when I say "I can use that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $E(\phi(X,Y)|X) = g(X)$, where $g(x) = E(\phi(x,Y))$." Maybe I'm just using it wrong?

To make discussion easier I would type all the relevant author's equations in mathjax and number them (maybe we don't need the whole proof). You should then also number your equations. Here is how you do it $$\tag1 and so on $$. I do not want to unravel the post as it is currently written.

@KurtG. is it any better now?

Yes. Much better. Let me think about it.

Let's go in steps. (A) first. We know from the link I gave in my first comment that $\mathbb{E}(\phi(X,Y) \mid X) = \mathbb{E}\phi(x,Y)|_{x=X}$ holds when $X,Y$ are independent. Have you heard of the Doob-Dynkin-lemma? It says that any $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable is a function of $X,,$ say, $g(X),.$ People often write this as $g(x)=\mathbb{E}(\phi(X,Y) \mid X=x),.$ If we apply this to what we know we find $g(x)=\mathbb{E}\phi(x,Y),.$ In the author's notation: $\mathbb{E}(\phi(X,Y) \mid x) = \mathbb{E}\phi(x,Y),.$ Makes sense?

That author's notation could be criticised but I think this is the only sensible interpretation.

@KurtG. So here, you're saying that $E(\phi(X,Y)|x) = g(x) = E\phi(x,Y)$. So my confusion is that for A, I interpret the LHS as $E((f(X)|x_1,\ldots, x_k) = g(x_1,\ldots, x_k) = E(f(x_1,\ldots,x_k, X_{k+1},\ldots, X_n)) \in \mathbb{R}$, a constant, but I interpret the RHS of A as  $f(x_1, \ldots, x_k, X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n)$, a random variable in $\mathbb{R}$

No. The author is smart enough not to write (in our toy example) $\mathbb E\phi(x{\color{red}|}Y),.$ In other words, the RHS of (A) is a number as well.

@KurtG. Ah really sorry. So when the author says expectation over $X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n$, they do not mean to take the conditional expectation, conditioned on  $X_{k+1}, \ldots, X_n$? So for the RHS side of $A$, let's say $f(x,y) = X+Y$, $k=1$. Then I understood the RHS to be $E_2(f(x_1, X_2)) = E(x_1+X_2|X_2) = x_1+E(X_2|X_2) = x_1+X_2$, hence I understood RHS of $A$ to be a random variable.

The RHS is an ordinary expectation. That comes from $Y$ being independent of $X,.$

@KurtG. Ah okay, I guess the $E_k$ is just meant to say that we're taking the integral over $(X_{k+1} ,\ldots, X_n)$. Then A makes sense to me.

That notation alone means nothing but the author attempted verbally to  make this clearer. This could all have been written in more standard notation but let's get on with it.
